# Should I inherit controller on my model class to be able to use Json();

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my models constructor I want to be able to use:

```
string s = Json(object);
```

The only way I can get `Json()` to work is if I make the model class inherit `Controller`.

I don't know enough to know if this is a bad thing but it strikes me as a warning that the model shouldnt be inheriting from controller.  Is this bad practice to use `Json()` inside model?  Is this putting too much logic inside a model?

If it matters is there another way to add reference to get `Json()` to work without inheriting controller?

Comment: Well, a model is not a controller, so I would say it should not inherit from it.  Have you figured out _why_ inheriting from `Controller` allows you to use the `Json` method?

Comment: That won't work at all.  `Json()` returns an `ActionResult`.

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+json+serializer

Comment: Why do you want to create a `JsonResult` from a model?

Comment: I want to store a Json string based on an object.  MVC 5 has Json.net installed by default and on their site I can see a JsonConvert() method but I cannot find a reference to get this method working (ctrl + . isnt showing anything)

Comment: @Guerilla, what do you intend to do with that json string after you've obtained it?  Are you not returning it to the client?

Comment: @Kirk yes and also saving to database, I guess I was just thinking to have it in Json format in the model to make it easier but the more I think about it the sillier it sounds, I should just store object in model and serialize when its needed in controller.  Sorry

Comment: @Guerrilla, yes, you've hit upon the idiomatic approach.

Comment: "using Newtonsoft.Json;" was what I was looking for.  Sorry again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not, you should not inherit Model from Controller.

ASP.Net MVC models are often just data transfer objects with minimal logic - [Yes or no: Should models in MVC contain application logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951445/yes-or-no-should-models-in-mvc-contain-application-logic). There are other views too [[MVC: Where to put business logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563229/mvc-where-to-put-business-logic?rq=1]), but there is no case where you would make "model" to be a Controller.

Note: You may be looking for [Parse JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp), not using `Controller.Json` that returns `ActionResult`.